# Can I register for C2DM (push notification) in my splash screen?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

Is it alright to register for C2DM in my splash screen?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class myMain extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.isplash);

    MediaPlayer mpSplash = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.musicsplash);
    mpSplash.start();

    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");

    registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));

    registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", "my email address");

    startService(registrationIntent);

    Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(4000);
                startActivity(new Intent("com.ishop.pizzaoven.CLEARSCREEN"));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              finally{
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    logoTimer.start(); 
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can register for C2DM wherever you like, and often the sooner the better, so the app is ready to receive the messages. Note you do not need to re-register EVERY time the app runs, register once, store it to prefs, and only register again if the pref is empty (e.g. after an uninstall/reinstall)

Comment: What will happen if google refreshes your registration number?
Quoted from http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#handling_reg 
"Google may periodically refresh the receiver ID"

Comment: The splash screen REQUESTS the registration ID, but the C2DM receiver will handle the response. It will handle any later updates to that registration ID (e.g. if it changes) in the same way. The question was about where to first request it.